# How to change background image dynamically depending on the url

Tags: javascript, css, url, background

I'm trying to change dynamically on page load, the background depending on which URL you are. But it doesn't work for me.

```
var camera1 = "url1";
var camera2 = "url2";
var camera3 = "url3";
var currenturl = window.location;
jQuery(function($)
{
  if(camera1 == currenturl) 
  {
    $(".breadcrumb-right").css("background", "url(url1.jpg)   !important;");
  }    
  else if (camera2 == currenturl) 
  {
    $(".breadcrumb-right").css("background-image", "url(url2.jpg)");
  }    
  else if (camera3 == currenturl) 
  { 
    $(".breadcrumb-right").css("background-image", "url(url3.jpg)");
  }    
});
```

Comment: create js fiddle if possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can improve your code doing something like this:

```
const cameras = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
const currentUrl = window.location.href;
const el = $(".breadcrumb-right");

if (cameras.includes(currentUrl)) {
  el.css("background-image", `url(${currentUrl})`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
It worked for me but i had to edit, creating cameras1 cameras 2 and cameras3. Otherwise it put for each room the same background...

Answer (score 0):

Be careful window.location doesn't return a string. 
Instead try using
`window.location.href` for full url (for example this page "[How to change background image dynamically depending on the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39369642/how-to-change-background-image-dinamycally-depend-on-url)" )

or

`window.location.pathname` for path only (for example this page "/questions/39369642/how-to-change-background-image-dinamycally-depend-on-url" )